# Azure Function Time Trigger doesn't log

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6 Azure Function App. My Azure Function App have one `HttpTrigger' and the other one is` TimerTrigger `In my Function Startup class, I have registered`builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()`. I have define any specific information to logging.

The HttpTrigger log works fine how I cannot see any log for TimeTrigger function

[image]

But I can see under kudu

[image]

```
[FunctionName("FileProcessingAdaptor")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("*/1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"AzureFunction: [Time-Trigger] [FileProcessingAdaptor] Executed At {DateTime.Now}");

            log.LogInformation($"AzureFunction: [Time-Trigger] [FileProcessingAdaptor] Executed At {DateTime.Now}");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

the both function log are based on same log but not sure what I am missing here

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
     builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpClientService, HttpClientServices>();

     builder.Services.AddLogging();

   builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
}
```

Comment: Can you share **Startup class** code?

Comment: @RajkumarPalnati-MT I have put code for startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to check. I came across an issue of logging to elastic search, and it can only log to Debug or Console, but not to elastic. It ended up that the Timer was too short as I set it to 1 s. After I set it to 5 seconds, it worked.